# Paraxial approximation in nonlinear optics

Tags: waves, non-linear-optics

I have a question about the paraxial approximation in nonlinear optics, it is different from the one in linear optics. and i'm confused about the difference between them, can anyone clarify this notion in nonlinear optics ? or just give me a reference that explains it very well.

Thanks

Omar

Comment: There's only one paraxial approximation - it's the same in linear and nonlinear optics. You're almost certainly mis-reading different sources that use different notation, so: what sources are you reading, and what gives you that impression?

Comment: I know the paraxial approx in linear optics, it has an impact on on the propagation considering the laser beams as superposition of rays which we used to do in geometric optics, but in nonlinear optics, the paraxial approximation has a relation with complex envelope of the wave and to find the paraxial approx, one has to consider the slowly varying envelop in space (time). This you can see in the book of nonlinear optics, the one of BOYD. Thanks

Comment: It would be good to summarize (in an edit to your question) what you think are the definitions in the linear and non-linear case (with sources). As of now, the question is still too unclear to answer. With that edit, it would be easier to contrast the definitions and see if they boil down to the same, or if there was simply some mis-reading as @EmilioPisanty noted.

Comment: @ahemmetter. What is the relation between the paraxial approximation we know in linear optics $sin(\theta) \approx \theta $ with the slowly varying envelop approximation in nonlinear optics, where we consider $A(r,t)$ the amplitude of a laser beam is slowly varying $A(r,t) = A_0$ there is non modulation of the amplitude due to the nonlinearities ?? this is exactly my question. Thanks

Comment: What exactly makes you think there is a connection between those things? As noted in the answer below, the relation in linear optics is purely a geometric simplification - in fact, it doesn't have anything to do with optics: it's just that the difference between the length of the hypotenuse and leg becomes smaller with decreasing angle. The other thing just seems to be a quasistatic approximation (the change in amplitude is so slow it can be treated as momentarily constant). I'm not sure where you found that these should be the same concept.

Comment: @ahemmetter in the books of Boyd Nonlinear optics, section of "Paraxial wave equation" page 116-117 in the third edition

Answer (score 1):

The paraxial approximation is great for basic optics calculations with lenses and light rays, it's just based on trigonometry where sin theta equals theta at small angles.  It concerns simplification of ray propagation.  In non-linear optics there are situations where it could be used but in general non-linear optics calculations involve field calculations and polarizations and are not simple ray exercises.

Comment: Yep you are right, it is a bit complicated, it has to do with the polarization and amplitudes of the field. and the important I think (not sure) is that it allows to find an expression of the complexe amplitude of the field that varies slowly, this has to do with the direction of the wavevector k and the poynting vector s. can you give me a confirmation or a clarification more. Thank you so much :)